# docker-machine, docker-compose and google cloud

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform, docker-compose, docker-machine

I want to create a `docker-machine` in `google cloud`.

I use the following command:

```
docker-machine create --driver google --google-project test-project --google-machine-type n1-standard-4 test-shiny
```

then, I put that machine in active state:

```
$ eval "$(docker-machine env cinepolis-shiny)"
```

and it succeded:

```
$ docker-machine ls
NAME              ACTIVE   DRIVER       STATE     URL                       SWARM   DOCKER    ERRORS
test-shiny   *        google       Running   tcp://XX.XXX.XX.XX:2376           v1.10.1   
dev          -        virtualbox   Stopped                                     Unknown
```

then I try it use `docker-compose --verbose up -d` (this works in `dev` and locally) and the following happens:

```
$ docker-compose --verbose up -d
compose.config.config.find: Using configuration files: ./docker-compose.yml
docker.auth.auth.load_config: Trying /home/nanounanue/.docker/config.json
docker.auth.auth.load_config: File doesn't exist
docker.auth.auth.load_config: Trying /home/nanounanue/.dockercfg
docker.auth.auth.load_config: File doesn't exist - returning empty config
compose.cli.command.get_client: docker-compose version 1.5.2, build 7240ff3
docker-py version: 1.5.0
CPython version: 2.7.9
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013
compose.cli.command.get_client: Docker base_url: https://23.236.56.24:2376
compose.cli.command.get_client: Docker version: KernelVersion=4.2.0-18-generic, Os=linux, BuildTime=2016-02-11T19:32:54.005620765+00:00, ApiVersion=1.22, Version=1.10.1, GitCommit=9e83765, Arch=amd64, GoVersion=go1.5.3
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers <- (all=True, filters={u'label': [u'com.docker.compose.project=docker', u'com.docker.compose.service=cinepolisdata', u'com.docker.compose.oneoff=False']})
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers -> (list with 0 items)
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers <- (all=True)
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers -> (list with 0 items)
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers <- (all=True, filters={u'label': [u'com.docker.compose.project=docker', u'com.docker.compose.service=server', u'com.docker.compose.oneoff=False']})
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers -> (list with 0 items)
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers <- (all=True)
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers -> (list with 0 items)
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers <- (all=True, filters={u'label': [u'com.docker.compose.project=docker', u'com.docker.compose.service=cinepolisdata', u'com.docker.compose.oneoff=False']})
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers -> (list with 0 items)
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers <- (all=True)
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers -> (list with 0 items)
compose.project._get_convergence_plans: server has upstream changes (cinepolisdata)
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers <- (all=True, filters={u'label': [u'com.docker.compose.project=docker', u'com.docker.compose.service=server', u'com.docker.compose.oneoff=False']})
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers -> (list with 0 items)
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers <- (all=True)
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker containers -> (list with 0 items)
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker inspect_image <- (u'docker_cinepolisdata')
compose.service.build: Building cinepolisdata
compose.cli.verbose_proxy.proxy_callable: docker build <- (pull=False, nocache=False, stream=True, tag=u'docker_cinepolisdata', forcerm=False, rm=True, path='/home/nanounanue/proyectos/klustera/docker/data', dockerfile=None)
docker.api.build._set_auth_headers: Looking for auth config
docker.api.build._set_auth_headers: No auth config in memory - loading from filesystem
docker.auth.auth.load_config: Trying /home/nanounanue/.docker/config.json
docker.auth.auth.load_config: File doesn't exist
docker.auth.auth.load_config: Trying /home/nanounanue/.dockercfg
docker.auth.auth.load_config: File doesn't exist - returning empty config
docker.api.build._set_auth_headers: No auth config found
```

and in this point hangs forever.

So, what I am doing wrong? How I can generate the `.dockercfg` file?

Could you give me pointers?

Note that I can use without problems `docker-machine ssh ...` and `docker run busybox echo 'Hello, World!'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the .dockercfg to be created, you need to run

```
docker login
```

More information can be found in this [article](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/login/).